Renumerate a column in a group
I'm looking for a scalable way to re-numerate groups (in my case cluster number) in a column. Below the current state with Pandas schema.
data = [
    ["Adam", 1, 22],
    ["Eddy", 0, 22],
    ["Boby", 9, 22],
    ["Timy", 2, 26],
    ["Carl", 9, 26],
    ["Anna", 0, 33],
    ["Paul", 5, 35],
    ["Mike", 7, 51],
]

current = pd.DataFrame(data,
                       columns=['name', 'score', 'cluster']
                       ).astype({'name':'string', 'score':'Int64', 'cluster':'Int64'})

current table looks like that:
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
|    | name   |   score |   cluster |
|----+--------+---------+-----------|
|  0 | Adam   |       1 |        22 |
|  1 | Eddy   |       0 |        22 |
|  2 | Boby   |       9 |        22 |
|  3 | Timy   |       2 |        26 |
|  4 | Carl   |       9 |        26 |
|  5 | Anna   |       0 |        33 |
|  6 | Paul   |       5 |        35 |
|  7 | Mike   |       7 |        51 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+

my desired state would be:
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
|    | name   |   score |   cluster |
|----+--------+---------+-----------|
|  0 | Adam   |       1 |         1 |
|  1 | Eddy   |       0 |         1 |
|  2 | Boby   |       9 |         1 |
|  3 | Timy   |       2 |         2 |
|  4 | Carl   |       9 |         2 |
|  5 | Anna   |       0 |         3 |
|  6 | Paul   |       5 |         4 |
|  7 | Mike   |       7 |         5 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+

Assume there will be millions of rows and hundreds of clusters. For a very small number of clusters, I can do it by hand, but I need a scalable solution.
I've tried to iterate over groups after .groupby("cluster") and to assign consecutive numbers but I failed.

You can use pd.factorize:
current['cluster'] = pd.factorize(current['cluster'])[0] + 1

Output:
   name  score  cluster
0  Adam      1        1
1  Eddy      0        1
2  Boby      9        1
3  Timy      2        2
4  Carl      9        2
5  Anna      0        3
6  Paul      5        4
7  Mike      7        5

The data doesn't have to be sorted for this to work.

For encoding, factorize is convenient in many cases, so I recommend this answer to the questioner. Just keep in mind that the result of factorize is a tuple of uniq and code, so you'll need to do indexing it as shown in this answer, which is very convenient.

A possible solution, which requires the dataframe to be sorted by cluster column:
current['cluster'] = (~current['cluster'].duplicated()).cumsum()

Output:
   name  score  cluster
0  Adam      1        1
1  Eddy      0        1
2  Boby      9        1
3  Timy      2        2
4  Carl      9        2
5  Anna      0        3
6  Paul      5        4
7  Mike      7        5

